# How to use custom CSS for two different Primefaces components

Tags: css

I would like to use two different CSS rules for two different components but of the same kind. For example the code below is the default code of a panelgrid in primefaces. I have two diffrent panelGrids( gridOne and gridTwo) which i wish could have diffrent CSS. I have tried using the styleClass in the XHTML code using different CSS rules but can somebody give a tip. I have read the  CSS specificity documents but I am still a little confused as both grids end up sharing the same CSS rule(especially when i add the **! important** )

```
 .ui-panelgrid .ui-panelgrid-cell {
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: inherit;
  padding: 4px 10px;
  }


 .gridOne,.ui-panelgrid .ui-panelgrid-cell {
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: red;
  padding: 0px;
  }


 .gridOne,.ui-panelgrid .ui-panelgrid-cell, .gridOne {
 border-width: 1px;
 border-style: solid;
 border-color: red;
 padding: 0px;
  }

  }

 .gridTwo,.ui-panelgrid .ui-panelgrid-cell {
  border-width: 0px;
  border-style: none;
  border-color: none;
  padding: 2px 5px;
  }


.gridTwo,.ui-panelgrid .ui-panelgrid-cell,.gridTwo{
 border-width: 0px;
 border-style: none;
 border-color: none;
 padding: 2px 5px;

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select specific classes like that

```
/* All elements with class="ui-panelgrid or ui-panelgrid-cell " */
  .ui-panelgrid .ui-panelgrid-cell {
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: inherit;
    padding: 4px 10px;
  }

/* All gridOne elements with class="ui-panelgrid or ui-panelgrid-cell " */
.gridOne.ui-panelgrid .ui-panelgrid-cell {
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: red;
    padding: 0px;
  }

/* All gridTwo elements with class="ui-panelgrid or ui-panelgrid-cell " */
.gridTwo.ui-panelgrid .ui-panelgrid-cell {
    border-width: 0px;
    border-style: none;
    border-color: none;
    padding: 2px 5px;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks bro, let me try it

Comment: It worked. But i need  clarification. What is the difference in your code and my code. What i mean is, when can one use **.gridTwo,.ui-panelgrid .ui-panelgrid-cell,.gridTwo**. That is a name followed by a comma instead of a fullstop?

Comment: If you want to select elements those have **.gridTwo** or **.ui-panelgrid** class, in the same selector you should use this **.gridTwo,.ui-panelgrid**. But if you want to select an element with these two classes simultaneously, you should use a full stop. Like this **.gridTwo.ui-panelgrid**

Comment: If you still have questions, this [link](https://css-tricks.com/multiple-class-id-selectors/) helps me to understand. You can check this.